# Counting variables and functions of copy-paste source

Tags: vb.net, function, parsing, variables

i need some help on counting variables and functions and print out their names in VB.net. For example, let's say we have a source code other than ours, and in our project we have a textbox and a button. I need to paste the third-party source code in the textbox and when i click the button i need to have an ouput like the one below:

Num of Variables: 10

Num of Functions: 5

Names of Variables: i,j,k....

Names of Functions: Func1, Func2...

I don't have an idea about what i ask, the only thing i did was searching online for days and found nothing.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you should search occurrences of special words like: **Dim, Sub, Function, Private, Public etc.** and valid combinations. Eg: After every **Dim** there will be one ore more Variables.

Comment: So, practically I should use "for each" and "split()" methods to do it? What do you suggest? Thanks for the answer!